# Download M3U8 That Is Playable

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to download a livestream from this traffic camera source:  https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/playlist.m3u8

The ffmpeg I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/playlist.m3u8 -preset slow -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 4500k -minrate 4500k -maxrate 9000k -bufsize 9000k -vf scale=-1:720 test.mp4
```

And here are the logs when I quit the recording:

```
ffmpeg version 5.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/chunklist_w259023283.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/media_w259023283_61526.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/media_w259023283_61527.ts' for reading
Input #0, hls, from 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/playlist.m3u8':
  Duration: N/A, start: 65276.905822, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 142637
  Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 142637
  Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 480x270 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 142637
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x120258000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x120278000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x120288000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x120298000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202a8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202b8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202c8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202d8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202e8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x1202f8000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x120248000] [swscaler @ 0x120308000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] using cpu capabilities: ARMv8 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] 264 - core 163 r3060 5db6aa6 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=15 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=4500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=9000 vbv_bufsize=9000 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 4500 kb/s, 15 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 142637
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 9000000/0/4500000 buffer size: 9000000 vbv_delay: N/A
[https @ 0x13201ce00] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/media_w259023283_61528.ts' for reading
[https @ 0x131814200] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/chunklist_w259023283.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[https @ 0x131814200] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/chunklist_w259023283.m3u8' for reading
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Skip ('#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0')
[https @ 0x13201ce00] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/media_w259023283_61529.ts' for reading
[tls @ 0x131606060] Error in the pull function.
[tls @ 0x131606060] IO error: End of file
[hls @ 0x1417050e0] Opening 'https://vss1live.dot.ga.gov/lo/alph-cam-002.stream/media_w259023283_61529.ts' for reading
^Cav_interleaved_write_frame(): Immediate exit requested93 bitrate=4697.0kbits/s speed=1.77x    
Error writing trailer of test.mp4: Immediate exit requested
frame=  610 fps= 23 q=4.0 Lsize=   20224kB time=00:00:36.13 bitrate=4585.1kbits/s speed=1.35x    
video:20500kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Error closing file test.mp4: Immediate exit requested
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] frame I:3     Avg QP: 2.13  size:192240
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] frame P:156   Avg QP: 0.44  size: 66488
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] frame B:451   Avg QP: 1.32  size: 28629
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] consecutive B-frames:  1.1%  0.3%  1.5% 97.0%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] mb I  I16..4: 21.7% 26.6% 51.7%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] mb P  I16..4:  2.9%  3.1% 11.0%  P16..4:  9.3%  4.1%  3.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:66.1%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.4%  1.6%  B16..8: 14.6%  4.0%  2.1%  direct: 3.2%  skip:73.9%  L0:53.1% L1:41.6% BI: 5.3%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] final ratefactor: -0.00
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] 8x8 transform intra:19.0% inter:11.1%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] direct mvs  spatial:98.2% temporal:1.8%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 91.5% 77.2% 76.6% inter: 11.8% 12.2% 11.9%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 54% 10% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 42% 15%  3%  5%  3%  7%  3%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 32% 13%  5%  9%  5%  9%  4%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 44% 13%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] ref P L0: 83.7%  3.3%  8.8%  2.4%  1.8%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] ref B L0: 79.9% 19.0%  0.8%  0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] ref B L1: 99.0%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x14169ff30] kb/s:4693.84
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Except the video doesn't seem to be playable by VLC or Quicktime. Given that the stream can end at any moment thus ending the file, how do I make the file actually playable?

Comment: post the ffmpeg log so we can see the codec info. Also, what if you re-encode?

Comment: @kesh logs is added

Comment: are you literally ctrl-c quitting the recording?

Comment: `Error writing trailer of test.mp4: Immediate exit requested` is likely the reason the output file not playable...